# Generate matrix from two columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                  'Call_loc': ['SJDR', 'SJDR', 'SJDR', 'TR', 'LD', 'LD'],
                  'Pres_Resid': ['SJDR', 'SJDR', 'TR', 'TR', 'LD', 'LD']})
df
```

I need to generate an array where the columns are the unique values of the `Call_loc` column and the indices are the unique values of the `Id` column. The matrix values will be filled by the number of times a value in `Call_loc` is repeated by `Id`. The expected output is this:

```
  |SJDR|TR |LD
1 | 2  | 0 | 0
2 | 1  | 1 | 0
3 | 0  | 0 | 2
```

I'm having trouble counting reps. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pbpython.com/pandas-crosstab.html):

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.Id, df.Call_loc)

     LD  SJDR  TR           
1    0     2   0
2    0     1   1
3    2     0   0
```

If column order is important, you can change it slightly:

```
cols = ['SJDR','TR','LD']
new = pd.crosstab(df.Id, df.Call_loc)[cols]
```

Comment: Tks, very simple!